# Code to Validate size of content while uploading into CMS

Tags: image

I need to restrict the user from uploading content to some limit like 2MB for an image.
I want that the user gets the message on save event that your content is greater then the allowed size.

Answer (score 6):

This can be implemented with the event system, using the Initiated phase (if you are on 2011 or higher). Simply use the FileInfo class to check the size, and throw an exception if it is too big.

Alternatively, you could modify the IIS settings to disallow uploads larger than 2MB.

Comment: @Quirjin: Where i can set this in IIs??

Comment: Check here: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented something similar, but based on the height and width of a component, but you could easily modify the code to check the size. The code is linked from [this article on Tridion Practice](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/UsingSemanticMultimediaSchemas).